# Как сделать дерево с более чем 2 ветками на уровне?

Tags: c, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Пытаюсь разобраться с деревьями. Все понятно с бинарными деревьями, но как быть, если мне надо, например больше 2 веток, например 4, и их всегда будет разное количество. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не, а проблема-то в чём? ну будут ссылаться на мамкин узел не два поддерева, а 4, и что?

Comment: Заведите в узлах списки ссылок на потомков и все будет хорошо

Comment: То, что всегда будет разное количество веток, ничего?

Comment: @Александр, слово "список" вам ни о чём не говорит? Ну или то же дерево.

Comment: @PinkTux - Ваше обращение к автору вопроса ПО SO переадресовало мне :)

Comment: Просто не особо с деревьями знаком. Я деревья представляю, как будто есть левая и правая ветка.

Answer (score 0):

> представляю, как будто есть левая и правая ветка

Есть список (массив) потомков.

```
Tree[T]:
  List[Tree[T]] children
  T value
  Tree parent

AddChild[T](T ob, Ref[Tree[T]] tree):
  child = Tree(value=ob, parent=tree)
  tree.children.add(child)

Walk[T](Tree[T] tree):
  for child in tree.children:
    Walk(child)
```